# Why am I getting different results for 2008 sql server and 2014 while tracing "Audit Add Member to DB Role Event"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-profiler

I have two sql servers: 2008 and 2014.
When I am trying to collect traces for "**Audit Add Member to DB Role**" event class, my 2008 server does not capture **TextData**, but 2014 does capture. But there is no information on msdn about TextData for this event class:
[Audit Add Member to DB Role Event Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189935.aspx)

Code to create traces:

```
DECLARE @TraceID int

DECLARE @FILESIZE bigint
set @FILESIZE = 5

DECLARE @FILEPATH nvarchar(256)
SET @FILEPATH = 'C:\Temp\Traces\trace'

DECLARE @StopTime datetime 
Set @StopTime = DATEADD( dd, 7, GETDATE())

exec sp_trace_create @TraceId=@TraceID OUT, @options=2, @tracefile=@FILEPATH, @maxfilesize=@FILESIZE, @stoptime=@StopTime
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID=@TraceID,@EventId=110,@ColumnId=1,@on=1
exec sp_trace_setstatus @traceid = @TraceID, @status = 1
```

Where

```
@EventId=110 - Audit Add Member to DB Role Event Class
@ColumnId=1 - TextData column.
```

When I execute:

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_accessadmin', 'TESTPC\TestGroup'
exec sp_droprolemember 'db_accessadmin', 'TESTPC\TestGroup'
```

I am getting results:

For 2008:

[image]

For 2014:

[image]

Is there any docs that I cant find on the web?